# Error When using Microsoft.DwayneNeed to solve WPF airspace isssue

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interpolation

I have a wpf app,which used winform control on the mainwindow.Of course ,this winform control stays ontop when a show a modal border. After that,I found Microsoft.DwayneNeed way to solve this problem.It works. But there's a new problem shows up. Let me describle my situation:

In the MainWindow,I have a Grid,which has three columns.The control in first column is a normal wpf control.The second column contains a Gridsplitter.And the third columns is where the winform control lays in.

Before I use AirspaceDecorator(From Microsoft.DwayneNeed)  as container of winform control,except the winform control always stays on topmost,every thing is ok, and GridSplitter works well.

After I use AirspaceDecorator as winform control's container, winform control doesn't stay topmost.It's good,it's what I want. But surprisingly, GridSplitter doesn't work any more:
1.Generayly,I can't drag GridSplitter --- it should be drag horizontally as designed.
2.On occassionly,GridSplitter will be dragged to the end of the left or the right edge of window .At this curcirmstance,the winform control occpies all the window,or zero.

I tried some ways,such as AirspaceFixer,using WinformHost to host dialoge border,etc. But none of these methods works.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing,I resolved this problem.The answer is to use AirspaceFixer correctly.

Before you call something show on winform control that wrapped by AirspaceFixer,you should set FixAirspace to true,and after you hide upper wpf control,you should set FixAreaSpace property to false. Just like it's demos shows up.